# Mysql variable not being written/read on each row

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
time   datetime
```

I just want to select the rows of that table giving two informations: the time present on that row and the time present on the row before, so that we could show a set of time-windows. For instance, using this records:

```
2017-07-01 20:00:00
2017-07-01 07:00:00
2017-04-04 23:52:00
```

would return the following time-windows:

```
2017-07-01 20:00:00 - null
2017-07-01 07:00:00 - 2017-07-01 20:00:00
2017-07-01 20:00:00 - 2017-04-04 23:52:00
```

I though about using variables, selecting the variable first and setting it on each row, being able to define a time-window like the following example:

```
SELECT @END_DATE date_time_to, @END_DATE := date_time date_time_from FROM (
  SELECT cast('2017-07-01 20:00:00' as DATETIME) AS date_time
  UNION
  SELECT cast('2017-07-01 07:00:00' as DATETIME) AS date_time
  UNION
  SELECT cast('2017-04-04 23:52:00' as DATETIME) AS date_time
) a ORDER BY date_time desc;
```

This works when variable is somehow set but on the first run it simply delivers the following result:

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| date_time_to | date_time_from      |
+--------------+---------------------+
| NULL         | 2017-07-01 20:00:00 |
| NULL         | 2017-07-01 07:00:00 |
| NULL         | 2017-04-04 23:52:00 |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

If I simply set null to the variable (`SET @END_DATE := NULL`) and try again I get:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| date_time_to        | date_time_from      |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| NULL                | 2017-07-01 20:00:00 |
| 2017-07-01 20:00:00 | 2017-07-01 07:00:00 |
| 2017-07-01 07:00:00 | 2017-04-04 23:52:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

which is the result I want, but whenever I use it on my application, I do not have any variables set and I'm constantly getting the result with the first column null What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the variable in a join.

```
SELECT @END_DATE date_time_to, @END_DATE := date_time date_time_from FROM (
  SELECT cast('2017-07-01 20:00:00' as DATETIME) AS date_time
  UNION
  SELECT cast('2017-07-01 07:00:00' as DATETIME) AS date_time
  UNION
  SELECT cast('2017-04-04 23:52:00' as DATETIME) AS date_time
) a 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @END_DATE := NULL) b
ORDER BY date_time desc;
```

Comment: nice! it worked, but why is it like that? I wasn't expecting that behavior.

Comment: Some kind of optimization, probably. There's a caveat in the documentation that says you can't depend on reading and writing the same variable in the same `SELECT` list, which probably allows this.